# css fix for chrome, and other web browsers

Tags: css, compatibility

I am looking for a fix for styling a webpage that so that a webpage on google chrome, will look the same as it does on firefox, meaning, is there some syntax in css to make all of the web browsers look the same. does this exist (I would also like one for I.E., and any other web browser if it exists if it exists)

Comment: I like to add...There is no easy solution for any website, including the ones built in Drupal to do this.

Comment: what about a drupal module to do it for me?

Comment: nope.  There are a million ways to do things, and browsers handle them all differently.   There is no way for a module to predict all of the million differences and solve them for you

Answer (score 4):

Google Chrome uses a different rendering engine than Internet Explorer/Firefox, so may display web pages differently. Apple Safari uses the same rendering engine as Google Chrome (WebKit) and should display pages the same way.

If your site isn't rendering properly in any browser, make sure your HTML and CSS are valid by testing them at http://validator.w3.org/.
If your site doesn't render properly in Google Chrome or Apple Safari, file a bug at webkit.org as described at http://webkit.org/quality/reporting.html.
If your site renders properly in Apple Safari but not in Google Chrome, please file a bug against Google Chrome at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list.

1. How can I test my website in Google Chrome?

There are several tools to help you test your website in Google Chrome:

Web Inspector
Right-click on any component on a web page to launch the web inspector. You'll be able to see the elements and resources associated with the component on which you clicked, including a hierarchy view of the DOM and a JavaScript console.
Task Manager
Select the Page menu icon, then Developer > Task Manager (or press Shift+Esc). The task manager shows all running Google Chrome processes, and the resources that they're using (memory, CPU, and network).
JavaScript Debugger
Select the Page menu icon, then Developer > Debug JavaScript. This launches a JavaScript debugger that can be used to attach to existing processes.

Answer (score 2):

I found the Answer. Being that I am using drupal, there is a built in IE fix for the theme that I am using (fusion) that creates separate css files (ie7.css, ie8.css, etc). using these, I can adjust what I need for IE specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Most layout problems with decent browsers are cause by invalid HTML, invalid CSS, or misunderstanding what a particular piece of CSS is actually supposed to do.

In general, when I see a difference between FF and Chrome, it is because Chrome is doing the proper thing and FF just happens to be rendering some invalid CSS fine.  99% of the time, I can fix the CSS and get FF and Chrome to render the same.

The remaining times, I typically browser sniff and use jQuery to fix the problem.